# Kerberize a python application

Tags: python, kerberos

I am writing a python application which performs several queries. I have used successfully the class here http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html
But if I have a lot of urls and i need to authenticate every url each time. As a result that makes my program very slow. My question is there any way to make a session with kerberos for my application? If that is not possible, is there any way to read a kerberos credential from the machine running the program so it can be authorized?

Comment: There isn't enough detail in your question to answer it. Show some code examples and what behaviour you want to eliminate.

Comment: http://privatepaste.com/2e22c8cf5a
Here is my code. Execution ends like following:
here
200
there
403
then
403

It seems that only the first url gets the certificate while I want as many as possible until the termination of the program